# intellij idea wsl 2 can't load projet from \\WSL.LOCALHOST\[distrib]

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With intellij idea version 2021.2.3, I can't open a project located in my Ubuntu WSL , path \wsl$\Ubuntu\home***
As soon as I point to the path the loading window closes

any idea ?

thank you by advane

it's work with Eclipse IDE.

I try this :

Here's how to do it (as of April 2023):

Open the IDE's property file: Help > Edit Custom Properties
Add the following on a new line:
ide.ui.new.file.chooser=true

Restart your IDE,

but not working

Comment: File a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this same issue and I figured out that the IntelliJ couldn't find the SDK (JDK) to load the project. I had no JDK in Windows neither WSL, so I had to install the the JDK in WSL and IntelliJ could find the SDK and load the project.

If the IntelliJ can't load the project even with SDK installed, try to open any other random folder and setup the SDK in Project Structure.